# VIM in GNU screen in Mac Terminal.app scrambled text

Tags: macos, vim, terminal

Trying to use Vim in Mac's Terminal.app but it's unusable, terminal is only refreshing line or column where the cursor is, so scrolling is quite bizarre. Text is being updated only on the line where the cursor is, but the rest is not changing. Very weird behavior, I've seen this on linux too, with nvidia driver, the bufferes somehow were not updated. It's driving me crazy, and forces me to use MacVim all the time.

The weird factor here, it only happens when I run Vim inside GNU screen, otherwise it works just fine.

Comment: Check your TERM environment variable. Also could try iterm2 - http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/ has a lot of features not supported in terminal.app (256 colors, mouse support)

Comment: Well, I had to edit the question, screen seems to cause that.

Comment: "that solved my issue" What did? Did you change the $TERM value? Did you just switch to iTerm2?

Answer (score 0):

try [MacVim](http://macvim.org/OSX/index.php) :)